Link in list of figures/tables don't lead to correct page with respective figure
When I click on the links in the list of figures/tables, I often get to the title page or to wrong pages (for some figures it works however - no apparent reason).
I use the packages:

hyperref
cleveref
tocbasic
tocloft

and then the code:
\newpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of figures}
\listoffigures
\newpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of tables}
\listoftables

Edit: Problem is solved when loading hyperref and cleveref AFTER tocloft and/or tocbasic.

show a small but complete example that demonstrates the problem. Without it is impossible to help you.

In my mwe it works fine - must be some sort of package interference?

a document that doesn't show the problem is not an example and so also not a minimal example. Start with a copy of your real document and remove stuff until you get an example that is small enough to be posted here.

It is possible to break a page at the start of the \listoffigres after \phantomsection.  For book class, it will always occur.  You need to modify the source for \listoffigurea etc.  (all the work is done by \@starttoc).

It´s {scrbook} class document. What @JohnKormylo said I already did. The problem is not that the Link section doesnt lead to the list of figures but that the figure links in the list do not reference to the correct figure.

My document has a few hundred pages and several sub-documents, so it will take a while to do what you suggest @UlrikeFischer. I will try and post it :)

@JohnKormylo you do not need to modify some source. You only need to use \cleardoublepage\phantomsection ... so that you are already on a odd page and then listoffigures will not produce another one.

@UlrikeFischer - At the time I didn't know it was book class.

@FantasticMsFox the most probable source of the problem is that you have duplicate page numbers or destination names. Look into the log-file if you find warnings.

scrbook has options to automatically add LoF, LoT etc. to the ToC, but you should not use tocloft with KOMA-Script classes, because it can break, e.g., those options. See the warnings in the log-file for more information.

I have tried back and forth and our problem is solved when loading hyperref and cleveref packages AFTER tocloft and/or tocbasic.
